# goto не выполняет свою функцию

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь применить goto в операторе switch. После введения двух отрицательных чисел, goto должен прыгать к метке в начало, чтобы пользователь ввёл числа заново, пока два числа не будут оба положительными, но goto не делает своей работы.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>

int calculate(int x, int y, char op)
{
try_again:
    std::cout << "Enter a first non-negative number: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "Enter a second non-negative number: ";
    std::cin >> y;
    std::cout << "Choose an operator: +, -, *, /: ";
    std::cin >> op;

    switch(op)
    {
        case '+':
            if((x && y) <  0)
                goto try_again;
            else
                return x + y;
            break;
        case '-':
            if((x && y) <  0)
                goto try_again;
            else
                return x - y;
            break;
        case '*':
            if((x && y) <  0)
                goto try_again;
            else
                return x * y;
            break;
        case '/':
            if((x && y) <  0)
                goto try_again;
            else
                return x / y;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int x, y;
    char op;
    std::cout << calculate(x, y, op) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Оператор `goto` здесь ни при чем, ведь условие проверки неверно. Чтобы проверить, являются ли два числа отрицательными, нужно как минимум написать `if (x < 0 && y < 0)`

Comment: вот так и рождаются мифы о goto... но хорошо бы условие вынести повыше - оно одно и тоже везде.

Comment: @Bogdan спасибо большое, действительно всё работает. У меня возник вопрос, почему `if ((x && y) < 0)` не работает? Я исходил из логики: если х и у меньше 0, то перейти к `goto`

Comment: @AlexGlebe спасибо большое за пояснение. Всё стало понятно :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if((x && y) <  0)
```

Начнем.

```
(x && y)
```

`&&` — логическое "И", значит, `x` и `y` переводятся в логические значения (равно нулю — `false`, не равно нулю — `true`, и вычислется логическое же значение `И` для них.

Далее - `<` — арифметика. `true` преобразуется в 1, `false` в 0, и выполняется сравнение. Очевидно, что в любом случае получается ложное значение — ни 1, ни 0 не меньше 0.

Правильно задавать вопрос не "если X и Y меньше 0", а "если X меньше 0 и Y меньше 0".
Думаю, теперь вы сможете закодировать условие сами?

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё стало понятно!

Answer (score 2):

оператор `&&` принимает только булевые переменные, и целые числа типа `int` преобразовывает на другой тип `bool`, который может принимать значения только ноль или единицу. Ваша запись `((x && y) < 0)` переводится компилятором как `(((x != 0) && (y != 0)) < 0)`, а так как результат может быть только `0` или `1`, то ответ всегда не будет приниматься.

Answer (score 2):

Не могу удержаться, чтобы не поправить. О том, что ошибка не в операторе `goto`, уже написали выше. Мои замечания в другом.

1. А вам обязательно использовать оператор `goto` по условию задачи, или такового условия изначально нет? Я про то, что `goto` - безусловно полезный инструмент, и в некоторых редких случаях без него действительно трудно обойтись. Однако всё же если есть возможность без ущерба для читабельности кода и производительности программы не использовать `goto`, следует `goto` не использовать. В вашем случае его легко можно заменить на цикл `while`.
2. Конструкция `if/else` и оператор `break` в вашем примере совершенно излишни и только загромождают код.

Ввиду выше изложенного, привожу улучшенный и исправленный (но не оптимизированный!) вариант вашей функции `calculate()`. На другие возможные ошибки я её не проверял, если что.

```
int calculate(int x, int y, char op)
{
    while (true)  //вместо try_again:
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a first non-negative number: ";
        std::cin >> x;
        std::cout << "Enter a second non-negative number: ";
        std::cin >> y;
        std::cout << "Choose an operator: +, -, *, /: ";
        std::cin >> op;
        
        switch(op)
        {
            case '+':
                if ((x<0) && (y<0))
                    continue; //вместо goto try_again;
                //else тут лишнее!
                return x + y;
                //break тут лишний!
            case '-':
                if ((x<0) && (y<0))
                    continue; //вместо goto try_again;
                return x - y;

            case '*':
                if ((x<0) && (y<0))
                    continue; //вместо goto try_again;
                return x * y;

            case '/':
                if ((x<0) && (y<0))
                    continue; //вместо goto try_again;
                return x / y;

            default:
                return false; //Возвращает bool, а тип результата int - не порядок!
                //break и тут не нужен!
        }
    } //while (true)
}
```

P.S. Заметил ещё один недочёт. У вас функция `calculate()` возвращает результат вычислений типа `int`, однако в ветке `default` у вас возвращается `false`. Будучи приведённым к типу `int` у вас возвратится в этом случае `0`. Если так и было задумано, то следует тогда написать `return 0`. Если нет, и для вас важно различать, был ли `0` результатом вычислений или некорректного ввода операции, то придётся изменить функцию. Исправлять не стал - самостоятельно, пожалуйста.

P.P.S. Как справедливо было замечено в комментариях, оператор `if` можно вообще вынести за `switch` - тогда код становится ещё лучше. Оптимизация))

```
int calculate(int x, int y, char op)
{
    while (true)  //вместо try_again:
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a first non-negative number: ";
        std::cin >> x;
        std::cout << "Enter a second non-negative number: ";
        std::cin >> y;
        std::cout << "Choose an operator: +, -, *, /: ";
        std::cin >> op;
        
        if ((x>=0) || (y>=0)) //инвертируем первоначальное условие, чтобы не писать continue
        {
            switch(op)
            {
                case '+': return x + y;
                case '-': return x - y;
                case '*': return x * y;
                case '/': return x / y;
                default:  return 0;  //будем пока так считать
            }
        }
    } //while (true)
}
```

Comment: не мог не удержаться и спросить, а Вы мой комментарий читали? может не нужно этот if пихать в каждый case? :)

Comment: @KoVadim комментарий не читал, но замечание справедливое. Оптимизация вообще-то и происходит по-этапно - сначала видишь одно, потом другое. Так что не надо так агриться. Свой ответ поправил, но предыдущий вариант оставил, так как он неплохо иллюстрирует мои первые два замечания.

Comment: а никто не "агрится". в вопросе был юмор, в комментарии такой же. Но видите как код сжался. Классно же.

Comment: @KoVadim полностью с вами согласен))

Comment: @LShadow77 благодарю за подробный ответ с примером! Я лишь пробую `goto` и мой код это просто мысли из головы, никакой практической значимости он не несёт, кроме как для тренировки. Я хотел попыться сделать что-то более сложное, чтобы разрастить код. Ваша поправка безусловно верная. Но это лишь моя тренировка :). Я не думаю, что в будущем мне постоянно будет нужен `goto`.

Comment: в общем случае почти всегда можно переписать код так, что бы он был без goto. В чистом си с goto иногда получается просто красивее код (классический пример - нужно открыть несколько файлов и не забыть их закрыть в случае ошибки. с goto - красиво, без - страшно)

Comment: @KoVadim другой, можно сказать, что классический пример: прерывание внешнего цикла внутри оператора `switch`. Использовать `break` нельзя, так как он зарезервирован в `switch` - остаётся `goto`, без которого получаются пляски с бубном.